# Merging maps with variables in Terraform

Tags: dictionary, merge, terraform

Running Terraform v0.11.3 and I am trying to merge two maps into a single map using the `merge()` function. However I can't get the syntax right. Does `merge()` support using dynamic variables?

```
  tags = "${merge({
    Name         = "${var.name}"
    Env          = "${var.environment}"
    AutoSnapshot = "${var.auto_snapshot}"
  }, "${var.tags}")}"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The syntax for `merge` in TF 0.11 is shown [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/interpolation.html#merge-map1-map2-):

```
${merge(map("a", "b"), map("c", "d"))}
```

So in your case, you should have something as follows:

```
tags = "${merge(map("Name", var.name,
                    "Env", var.environment,
                    "AutoSnapshot", var.auto_snapshot
               ), var.tags)}"
```

Comment: Ahh thanks so much. `map()` was throwing me off instead of just using `{}`

Answer (score 20):

In Terraform > 0.12 this can be done as:

```
tags = merge(tomap({
    Name = var.name,
    Env  = var.environment,
    AutoSnapshot = var.auto_snapshot }),
    var.tags,
)
```

Comment: Can someone clarify more why Terraform documents ["Maps/Objects"](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/types#maps-objects) not as separate types? It seems in many cases the curly braces are implicitly convert to Map type, but in others you must explicitly do the conversion and that's very counter-intuitive.